# Item count should be 10 but is 0

Tags: sharepoint, guid, splistitem

the items.count should be atlease 10. I have 10 subfolders (Release 1 ..... Release 10) with in this documnent library "Auto Cad" and each subfolder has a file called license.txt. hmmm
Why this is not returning any file(s)?

```
private void btnGetFileGuid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://www.abc.com/sites/Software"))
 { 
 using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
 { 
  SPList spList = web.Lists["Auto Cad"];
  string fileName = "license.txt"; 
  SPQuery query = new SPQuery(); 
  query.Query="<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>" + fileName + "</Value></Eq></Where>"; 
  SPListItemCollection items = spList.GetItems(query); 
  if (items.Count > 0) 
   { 
    Guid id = items[0].UniqueId; 
    lblGuid.Text = id.ToString(); 
   } 
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting so that your code snippet is more readable.

Comment: Drew, I can see the code block in the gray area and each code line has it's own line. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPQuery only searches a particular folder - to recursively search through subfolders you need to set

[SPQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewattributes.aspx)

So your code should be

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery(); 
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
query.Query=".... REST OF YOUR CODE HERE "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
query.Query="" + fileName + "";
```

This line is wrong. This should be CAML query and not name of filename.

Comment: The post is now edited. When I saw the post, it was Query="license.txt".

Comment: And before you give the comment of my posting as intention of scoring points. Have etiquette on having good subject "Em3rgency kinda situ@tion"

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a recursive call use the solution provided in question link provided below

i would recommend use qry.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'"; to get documents and folders as well
[query to get all items in a list including items in the sub folders in sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192873/query-to-get-all-items-in-a-list-including-items-in-the-sub-folders-in-sharepoint/4193120#4193120)

Comment: ashutosh: looks like Ryan's type solution. I will sure to try this one as well. What's the main difference between these two?

Comment: if you see the link provided with the answer and see their it answers the question you have asked

Comment: How does an identical answer that came hours after get more up votes? Points jealousy much ;)

Comment: Recursive returns all files from all subfolders - RecursiveAll returns both Files AND folders from all subfolders. Basically RecursiveAll does exactly the same in this context as he's looking for files, not folders. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spviewscope.aspx

Comment: @Ryan - See here for a discussion about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72439/reason-for-loss-of-reputation